# How do you set environment variables for a single command on Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Is there a way to set environment variables for a single command on Windows like `ENVVAR=abc command` on Unix?

Variables set by `set` command on Windows seem to remain for the following commands, but this is not what I want.

Comment: I think you will have to unset them yourself.

Comment: Not a duplicate - that other one is specific to CMD, this does not exclude powershell

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Is there a way to set environment variables for a single command?

**From the current `cmd` shell:**

You have to clear the variable yourself.

```
set "ENVVAR=abc" && dir & set ENVVAR=
```

**From a batch file:**

You can use `setlocal` and `endlocal`.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
  set "ENVVAR=abc" && dir
endlocal
```

**Use a child `cmd` shell:**

You can use `cmd /c` to create a child shell.

The variable is set in the child shell and doesn't affect the parent shell (as pointed out in a comment by [jpmc26](https://superuser.com/users/156577/jpmc26)).

```
cmd /C "set ENVVAR=abc && dir"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.
- [endlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) - End localisation of environment changes in a batch file. Pass variables from one batch file to another.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Comment: Another option is to launch a separate `cmd` process and set them there. E.g., `cmd /C "set ENVVAR=abc && dir"`. Since it won't affect the parent process, it will be effectively "cleared" on exit.

Comment: @jpmc26 Good one. Thanks. Added to answer.

Comment: That first method won't clear the variable if the command fails.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks. Good point. Answer fixed.

Comment: Beware: This does not set ENVVAR to the string `abc` but to `abc `! The extra space can simply be fixed by leaving it out before the `&&`. You might want to edit your answer, maybe even explicitly pointing out this issue because it might be surprising for unix affine people. It's extra hard to debug because output of `set` without any parameters when copied from a cmd.exe window does not include such trailing spaces!