# Does Windows7(+) have the env or equivalent? (Env. variable for single run of application)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I'm looking for an opportunity to launch an application (eg, compilers) with specific environment variables . I want same functionality like `env` in Linux.
`env var=value application.exe`

I found [Setting environment variable for just one command in Windows cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-environment-variable-for-just-one-command-in-windows-cmd-exe) but not satisfied with the decision.
(because it has a lot of character in the writing which you can make a mistake )

Something changed from 2010 year ? I would be happy  not even with  builtin solutions.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the solution in your link?

Comment: ugly, too much symbols

Comment: There isn't any other way ...

Comment: @DavidPostill please take a glance at [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1079415/376602)

Comment: @JosefZ As the OP said "ugly, too much symbols" ;) I know it can be done and your answer doesn't add much to what is already in [Setting environment variable for just one command in Windows cmd.exe](http://superuser.com/q/223104)

Comment: @DavidPostill I beg your pardon for my ineptness. I didn't read more than accepted answer:) because of _that_ OP's comment .

Comment: comment using env.bat by AFH in original question was writed AFTER my question. check timestamps. and he contain errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env var=value application.exe`

is possible. Write following batch script, name it `env.bat` and place it somewhere in a directory from your [PATH variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html). Please read [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) articles for further explanation.

**env.bat** script:

```
@setlocal
@set "%~1=%~2"
@%3
```

Above script applies to given simple command but would require to be a bit elaborated to accept line parameters like `env var=value application.exe action input output` etc.

---

**Before edit**:

```
set var=value&application.exe&set var=
```

i.e. set variable then run a *console* application and then remove variable.

Another approach:

```
cmd /C "set var=value&application.exe"
```

i.e. start a new instance of the Windows command interpreter and *within it* set variable then run a *console* application; for `/C` switch meaning see `cmd /?`:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

Here [`&` ampersand](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) must be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in *the command specified*. You could choose any:

```
cmd /C "set var=value&application.exe"
```

or

```
cmd /C set var=value^&application.exe
```

Note proper spacing as well:

```
                       ↓ allowed space                    
cmd /C "set var=value & application.exe"
                     ↑  this is harmful space as "%var%" would be "value " then
                                                    note trailing space ↑
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: If `value` contain a `;` colon (command separator) then `env.bat` fails to work correctly, eg `env var=ab;cdef` or `env var=%path%`. The value of `var` gets truncated at the `;` and the rest of the parameters get messed up. I don't know how to easily fix that.

Comment: @DavidPostill Semicolon is a [delimiter](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in `cmd` and should be escaped using double quotes as follows: `env var="ab;cdef"`. BTW, a script can't be concurrently simple and bullet-proof (if we can believe in existence of such oxymoronic thing as "_bullet-proof script_" .

Comment: Please improve your answer is to use a multi-setting variables

Comment: @RedSkotina are you asking for a _fully functional_ emulator of [Linux and Unix `env` command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uenv.htm)?  This would be a challenging task but requires herculean effort… Such task transcends current question topic. Moreover, let's consider current thread closed (*duplicate* at present). Please ask a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/ having in mind their  [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide. Show your own effort…

Comment: My questions will be closed in the same way people who think that I have to be satisfied with existing solutions.

Comment: The behaviour of the above solution does not truly emulate the behaviour of the Unix env command, becuase it spawns a subprocess i.e. cmd.exe -> application.exe
Whereas env uses the exec* family of system calls to replace the running process env.exe with the new application.exe process