# How to start cmd, run a long-running GUI program, then close cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need this when config [Listary](http://www.listary.com/)'s custom command to load `Rconsole` within Explorer, with environment variable `R_USER` set to current directory for this very command.

What I currently use is effectively same as

```
cmd /C "set R_USER=%path%&& C:\path\to\Rgui.exe"
```

(which I learn from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe) to set environment variable.)

It works fine, except open an extra window for cmd itself. which adds hassle to switch application with <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd>.

How can I achieve same workflow but without open the window for cmd itself?

P.S.  (Listary handle the substitution part and run the specified command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `start` command before your executable file path.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the CMD window to automatically close, you can launch a program like so:

```
start /min "" "path_to_your_program"
```

The `start` command tells Windows to execute another CMD window outside the scope of the current CMD. The `/min` starts the CMD window minimized, and isn't necessary.
The first set of double-quotes is definitely necessary, though anything can be placed within those quotes.
The second set must contain the absolute path to your program inside.