# how to archive file older then 5 days with 7z command

Tags: 7-zip

```
REM Exclude file types for archiving
REM set EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES=-x!*.rar -x!*.zip -x!*.7z
set EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES=-xr!*.zip 

REM Delete files after archiving
set DELETE_AFTER_ARCHIVE=-sdel

REM Archive files only older then days
REM set ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN=-to5d
set ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN=-5

set EXTRA_PARAM=%EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES% %DELETE_AFTER_ARCHIVE% %ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN%


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%
REM $Env:Path = $Env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

REM Set your WinRAR installation path for local testing
REM set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%


REM Replace space in hour with zero if it's less than 10
SET hr=%time:~0,2%
IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%

REM This sets the date like this: mm-dd-yr-hrminsecs1/100secs
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%


IF EXIST %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR% (
    cd %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR%
    7z a "%EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY%" %EXTRA_PARAM%
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question im getting error when im running this code.C:\apps\harmony\data\edi832\US\archive>7z a "%EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY%" %EXTRA_PARAM%


Command Line Error:
Unknown switch:
-5

Comment: So what is the error? And what line is it on?

Comment: %EXTRA_PARAM% giving the error due to set ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN=-5

Comment: You have to find the files older that 5 days first and then pass that list to 7z. See [7-Zip / Discussion / Help: How to: Specific Date and Time](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/316ab110/)

Comment: Why do you say Path to Winrar but actually put the path to 7zip...?

Comment: hi it was WINRAR previously since there is some security issue in my server i need to change it to 7z..just ignore the Rar comment

Comment: How do you want to save the files older then 5 days every file in its own zip or all files in 1 zip or how?

Comment: hi all files in one zip

Comment: I do not use 7-Zip and therefore don't know if 7-Zip has a switch similar to -to5d and files matched the criteria for archiving.

Comment: 7-zip doesn't have all the needed parameters ? if you could add that too you deserve a gold star :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I archive files older then 5 days with 7-Zip?

Unfortunately, 7-Zip currently doesn't have an option to filter files by age/date (as far as I am aware).

However, based on the [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/316ab110/) given in the comments by @DavidPostill suggesting the Windows [forfiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) utility, you may be able to use something similar to:

```
@REM Set the file list name used with 7-Zip
set FILE_LIST=file_list.txt

    if exist %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR% (

        cd %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR%

        @REM 7z a %EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY% %EXTRA_PARAM%

        @REM forfiles /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /v /c set newpath=@RELPATH && echo !newpath:.\=!" > file_list.txt
        forfiles /s /m *.* /d %ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN% /c "cmd /v /c set newpath=@RELPATH && echo !newpath:.\=!" > %FILE_LIST%

        @REM 7z a %EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY% %EXTRA_PARAM% @file_list.txt
        7z a %EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY% %EXTRA_PARAM% @%FILE_LIST%

        @REM del file_list.txt
        @REM del %FILE_LIST%

        )
```

In this case, the `forfiles` example above should generate a list of files (`> file_list.txt`) older than 5 days with full paths to each file in the format:

```
"filename.ext" 
"subfolder\filename.ext"
```

which can then be passed to 7zip as ex. `@file_list.txt`.

---

**forfiles Example Command**

Breaking down the example [forfiles command options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles):

- `/s` means recurse subdirectories.
- `/m` is the file mask (in this example, this includes all files and extensions via `*.*`).
- `/d` sets the age of files to include/exclude (based on their last modified dates). The example above will include files older than 5 days (`-5`). The current day is included in this calculation, so files up to 4 days prior *aren't* considered (i.e. won't be added to this list).
- `/c` specifies the command to run on each file. The command:

  ```
  cmd /v /c set newpath=@RELPATH && echo !newpath:.\=!
  ```

  works as follows:

  - `cmd /v /c` runs a new instance of [cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) (the Windows command prompt) with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled (`/v`) and closes that instance of `cmd` immediately after finishing the command (`/c`).
  - `set newpath=@RELPATH` creates a temporary variable called `newpath` and sets it to the value `@RELPATH`. `@RELPATH` is a relative path to a file created automatically by `forfiles` in the form ex. ".\filename.ext" (where `.\` means the current folder).
  - `echo !newpath:.\=!` prints a modified version of `newpath`. The `:.\=!` portion attached to `newpath` is actually a DOS string variable manipulation which says to replace all instance of `.\` with nothing (`=`). The `!` signs are used in place of `%` to reference variables when delayed expansion is enabled (so ex. `!newpath!` instead of `%newpath%`).
  - `&&` simply allows the two separate `set` and `echo` commands above to be placed/executed on one line.

---

**Notes**

- `newpath` can be called anything you wish.
- 7-Zip's `-x` and `-sdel` options should be honored by 7-Zip, even when using a file list.
- The command to set/use a variable in one line was adapted from an answer to [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe).

**Caveats**

- `.\` needs to be stripped from the relative paths passed to 7-Zip in order to maintain a relative directory structure. Otherwise, leaving `.\` in causes 7-Zip to "flatten" everything by placing all the the zipped files in the root of the archive (i.e. no subfolders).
- When reading from a list generated by `forfiles`, some character differences may cause 7-Zip to skip files. For instance, using `’` instead of `'` in a file name may result in a "file not found" warning (and thus these files won't be added to a given archive).
- Using `cmd /c` with `forfiles` adds a bit of overhead to processing each file (compared to running commands directly without `cmd`) but [bypasses any potential bugs where a command might fail](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).
- Using double quotes with `/c "cmd /c [...]"` is necessary to prevent `forfiles` from complaining about using `/c` twice.
- The [Super User question linked above](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe) notes that using `cmd /c /v` (rather than `cmd /v /c`) likely will *not* work.
- The `forfiles` command given was tested on Windows 7. However, in the same Super User question already linked, one comment reported an issue with combining similar commands on Windows 10 (version 1607), apparently due to a trailing space.
- In context, it seems unlikely the "trailing space" issue noted above would be relevant here, but if so, you could either try using "internal quotes" (as suggested in the linked question) or just use `"cmd /c echo @RELPATH"` in `forfiles` instead and use another command line utility to clean `.\` (and any other undesirable characters) from each line in `file_list.txt`.
- You can add files individually to an archive with `forfiles` (bypassing the need for ex. `file_list.txt`) but this is a *much* slower process (relatively speaking), as the archive will typically need to be decompressed/recompressed repeatedly for each file added.

Comment: this is awesome .thanks for the detail explanation .let me see how i can use forfiles command. many thanks ..i really apperciate it

Comment: Hi Man, this working perfectly and i have tested that .. The explanation pretty clear and very easy to understand.Your expertise and enthusiasm were both appreciated for guiding and helping me with great explanation

Comment: Your welcome. I am glad this was helpful to you. =)

Comment: Hi @Anaksunaman  Do i need delete the file after the archive , i have seen its comment out ? REM del file_list.txt
   REM del %FILE_LIST%

Comment: *"Do I need to delete the file after the archive?"* - No, you don't. `file_list.txt` should be overwritten by `forfiles` each run (meaning there should be no problem with leaving `file_list.txt` in place). Those lines are intended as completely optional examples. Many scripts will clean up temporary files once completed. Using either of those lines is just a matter of preference (in case you may not want extra files lying around after you archive everything). Obviously, you only need one to delete e.g.`file_list.txt` but they both can be removed if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

/d %ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN%
/d -%ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN%

Comment: Hello, please provide more information within your answers, it definitely shouldn't be just code/commands, unexplained in any way.